# can not add foreign key

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I wrote some migration but the foreign key's will not be added and give me the low error.

I dont see everything is suspicious.

## General error : 1251 cannot add foreign key constraint (SQL:alter table 'advertising' add constraint 'advertising_category_id_foreign' foreign key ('category_id')refrences 'category' ('id') on delete restrict on update cascade)

I change id type in related migration's,but it didn't work.

I turned the id in related migration's to index(),but agane didn't work.

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('advertising', function (Blueprint $table){
            $table->increments('id')->index();
            $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned()->index();
            $table->string('ranking')->nullable();
            $table->string('status')->nullable();
            $table->string('name')->nullable();
            $table->string('family')->nullable();
            $table->string('advertising_name')->nullable();
            $table->string('phone')->nullable();
            $table->string('email')->nullable();
            $table->string('address')->nullable();
            $table->string('country-city')->nullable();
            $table->integer('category_id')->unsigned()->nullable();
            $table->string('week_days')->nullable();
            $table->string('time_open')->nullable();
            $table->string('time_close')->nullable();
            $table->string('body')->nullable();
            $table->string('facebook')->nullable();
            $table->string('twitter')->nullable();
            $table->string('instagram')->nullable();
            $table->integer('service_garanti_id')->unsigned()->nullable();
            $table->integer('professional_id')->unsigned()->nullable();
            $table->integer('insurance_Limit_id')->unsigned()->nullable();
            $table->timestamps();


            $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users')
            ->onDelete('cascade')->onUpdate('cascade');
            $table->foreign('category_id')->references('id')->on('category')
            ->onDelete('restrict')->onUpdate('cascade');
            $table->foreign('service_garanti_id')->references('id')
            ->on('service_garanti')
            ->onDelete('restrict')->onUpdate('cascade');
            $table->foreign('professional_id')->references('id')
            ->on('professional')->onDelete('restrict')->onUpdate('cascade');
            $table->foreign('insurance_Limit_id')->references('id')
            ->on('insurance_limit')
            ->onDelete('restrict')->onUpdate('cascade');
        });
```

The related migration's :

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('category', function (Blueprint $table){
             $table->increments('id');
             $table->string('body')->nullable();
             $table->timestamps();

        });
```

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('service_garanti', function (Blueprint $table){
            $table->increments('id')->index();
            $table->string('body')->nullable();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
```

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('Professional', function (Blueprint $table){
            $table->increments('id')->index;
            $table->string('body')->nullable();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
```

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('Insurance_Limit', function (Blueprint $table){
            $table->increments('id')->index();
            $table->string('body')->nullable();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing the order of your migrations so that the tables containing the foreign values are created first (category, service_garanti, etc.) and then create the advertising table and make the key connections.  The tables and columns must already exist in order for the migration to succeed.

The other option if you know the keys are correct and will be created, it to just disable the key checking at runtime by adding this to the top of your migration.

```
public function up(){
   Schema::disableForeignKeyConstraints();

   Schema::create('advertising', function (Blueprint $table){
      ...
   }
}
```